# How to create timeline by adding same intervals x number of times? - SQL

Tags: sql, database, time, google-bigquery, window-functions

I want to create a table with timeline data by repeatedly adding the same intervals for each `id` a certain # of times denoted by `iterations` (constant per `id`). My current table has the base repetition of this timeline.

Sample Input (iteration 1):

```
id    start_time         end_time           iterations
1     00:00:00.00000     00:00:00.05300     3
1     00:00:00.05300     00:00:00.07600     3
```

Desired Output:

```
id    start_time         end_time       
1     00:00:00.00000     00:00:00.05300
1     00:00:00.05300     00:00:00.07600
1     00:00:00.07600     00:00:00.12900
1     00:00:00.12900     00:00:00.15200 
1     00:00:00.15200     00:00:00.20500
1     00:00:00.20500     00:00:00.22800
```

Logic:

- iteration 2: first end_time = 0.076 + (0.053 - 0.000) = 0.129
- iteration 2: second end_time = 0.129 + (0.076 - 0.053) = 0.152
- iteration 3: first end_time = 0.152 + (0.053 - 0.000) = 0.205
- iteration 3: second end_time = 0.205 + (0.076 - 0.053) = 0.228

What I've Tried:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
  *
  , SUM(TIME_DIFF(end_time, start_time, MILLISECOND)) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_time 
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        AS running_end_time
FROM my_table 
  , UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, iterations))
)

SELECT
  id
  , CASE 
       WHEN MIN(aggregated_start_time) OVER (PARTITION BY id) = FIRST_VALUE 
         OVER (PARTITION BY id) THEN TIME(0, 0, 0)
       ELSE LAG(TIME(0, 0, 0), INTERVAL running_end_time MILLISECOND) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY id) END AS start_time
  , TIME_ADD(TIME(0, 0, 0), INTERVAL running_end_time MILLISECOND)
        AS end_time 
FROM cte
```

However, this doesn't work because although my `cte` creates the necessary number of records, it doesn't order them the right way which leads to adding the wrong intervals. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: If **iterations** is 3,  how input and out will look like ?  3 input rows are given and output will be 6 rows with 1st, 2nd and 3rd end_time ?

Comment: updated post to show result with 3 iterations with same input. really appreciate helping with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, 
  time_add(start_time, interval repeat*step millisecond) as start_time,
  time_add(end_time, interval repeat*step millisecond) as end_time,
from (
  select *, 
    sum(time_diff(end_time, start_time, millisecond)) over(partition by id) step,
    max(end_time) over(partition by id) max_end_time
  from your_table
), unnest(generate_array(0, iterations - 1)) repeat
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]